# make width of a div equal to width of the screen, regardless of the width of its containing div

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have two divs:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    I want this div to take the width of the browser!
  </div>
</div>
```

`#container` div has a width bigger than the screen width. I want the div `#content` to take the width of the browser. I am making my website responsive, when the phone is in regular position, browser size is 320, and when it is horizontal, it's 480. I want the `#content` to responsively change width.

How can I do that? Thanks

**EDIT**

I think that I cannot use css. I should have explained this earlier, but the problem with using absolute positioning in css is that I need to keep the position of #content relative, container is a slider containing 3 #content divs. when I slide with finger, I want the active div to take width of the screen. so I can't really use absolute positionning!

Comment: a width of 9000 ? wat ... why ?

Comment: who cares, hypothetically speaking

Comment: you will never need smth like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#content').width($(this).width());
}).resize();
```

Comment: Isn't that going to loop permanently?

Comment: should I put it in a $(document).ready(function(){  }); ?

Comment: `.resize();` isnt necessary

Comment: @user3618369 Yes, you need to do it if you put your scripts in the head section of your page.

Comment: I feel that you should mention that fixing display or style issues with javascript is usually bad practice unless there's no other way

Comment: @Felix Why do we need jquery when we can do this with CSS itself?

Comment: @jammypeach & mohamedrias Yes, you both are correct, OP's problem surely can be solved with pure CSS. I just provide an alternative solution since OP is not providing enough details.

Comment: +1 Because in all likelihood, CSS won't be enough

Comment: @Felix Exactly as the OP wants to have responsive web design, media queries are meant for that. I dont know why i got downvotes for that :D

Comment: @mohamedrias Because your answer doesn't actually solve the OP's question.

Comment: I think that I cannot use css. I should have explained this in my question, but the problem with using absolute positioning in css is that I need to keep the position of #content relative, container is a slider containing 3 `#content` divs. when I slide with finger, I want the active div to take width of the screen. so I can't really use absolute positionning!

Comment: Okay felix your solution is the best, it worked with what i needed.. huge thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth does `#content` have a width of 9000? It sounds like there is probably a better way to implement your design.

That said, the below will work:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/p5EUa/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">I want this div to take the width of the browser!</div>&nbsp;
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
#container {
    width:9000px;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that I need to keep the position of #content relative, container is a slider containing 3 `#content` divs. when I slide with finger, I want the active div to take width of the screen. so I can't really use absolute positionning!

Comment: @user3618369 - you wont be able to do this then I'm afraid due to the cascading nature of CSS. You'll either need to use JS (ugly) or rethink your layout.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this in CSS and HTML.

First, in html use a viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

then in css use:

```
body{
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

#container{
width:9000px; 
height:200px;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

On a side note - why is your container 9000px?

it's always best practise to impliment your CSS as fluid structure rather than set widths - so try the following instead:

```
#container{
width:100%;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
}

#content {
width:auto;
height:100%;
}
```

Presuming you're after a scrollable content that takes full width anyway.

Comment: Please insert proper css selectors. Both of them are wrong as per the question

Comment: That is a writing choice, Not a definitive thing - If he wants to use ID's let him use them, as long as they aren't duplicated - he is still in his rights to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `CSS` using `position:absolute` on `#content` and then setting your width, which in this case is 100%:

```
#content { position: absolute; width: 100%; }
```

***[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wmbv7/)***

However, this only works if none of it's parent elements have `position:relative` on. If they do, I'd use Felix's answer

Comment: A fiddle is not a substitute for putting the code in the answer.

Comment: @Liam But the code you've put in my answer isn't relevant to the answer

Comment: that's the code out of your fiddle?!

Comment: @Liam But about 60% of it was for illustration purposes. Please don't edit changing an answer if you can't actually be bothered to **improve** the answer by adding the **relevant** information.

Comment: @jumpingcode perhaps pasting the rest in from your fiddle would be the way to go then?

Comment: @jammypeach The above is all that is needed to answer the question. Anything else is illustration and noise.

Comment: @jumpingcode ah I see, just reviewed the edits. nothing to see here, moving along...

Answer (score -1):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/Wmbv7/1/)

It can be done using CSS itself:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to customize the background and other properties based on the screen resolution, then media queries is the best option

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   #content {
        width: 480px !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 30px) {
   #content {
        width: 480px !important;
  }
}
```